# $_POST sem fechar modal bootstrap

Tags: post, modal

Tenho que abrir um formulario em um modal usando bootstrap e ao enviá-lo quero receber os dados sem fechar o modal

Abro o modal assim:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEMP" href="consulta.php">Consultar CNPJ</a>
```

O arquivo consulta.php tem o seguinte formulario:

```
<form id="formulario" action="resultado.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="CNPJ" id="CNPJ" maxlength="19" required />
    <input id="submit" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar" />
</form>
```

Desta forma ao enviar o formulario o modal fecha automaticamente. Quero que seja enviado o post e me mostre a pagina *resultado.php* no mesmo modal.

Answer (score 1):

Com essa forma de enviar, a página atualiza completamente e retorna a modal para padrão inicial(que é hidden).
Use jquery e ajax para dar um submit no formulário.

```
<form id="formulario" action="resultado.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="CNPJ" id="CNPJ" maxlength="19" required />
    <input id="submit" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#formulario');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```